# Disable rounding in jQuery knob library

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-knob

I have a float value, that comes from JSON data. Calling `console.log()` displays the correct value `fe: 12.3`. But I don't know why, when I try to set this value with `val()` it rounds the value `fe: 12.0`?

If the value is `23.4`, displays `23.0`. If `31.8`, displays `32.0`.

This is the snippet in which I want to set the value:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var color = 'green'
  $('.dial').knob({
    'min': 0,
    'max': 100,
    'width': "100%",
    'height': "100%",
    'displayInput': true,
    'fgColor': color,
    'readOnly': true,
    'draw': function() {
      $(this.i)
        .val(this.cv.toFixed(1) + 'ms')
        .css('font-size', '15pt')
        .css('color', 'black');
    }
  });
});
```

And this is the code that sets the value:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "stats.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: data
}).done(function(answer) {
  console.log(answer)
  time = answer.TIME
  time = parseFloat(time)
  $(<?php echo "host".$i ?>).val(time);
  $(<?php echo "host".$i ?>).trigger('change');
  setColor();
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try this `parseFloat(time).toFixed(2)`

Comment: I think it supports float values, because until now my knob was working correctly displaying the correct data. I have started to have this problem since i set the value with jquery val() :( Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default jQuery Knob only supports integers. To make it correctly format floating point values, you need to set the `step` parameter to the level of accuracy you require. In this case, `0.1`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var color = 'green'

  $('.dial').knob({
    min: 0.0,
    max: 100.0,
    step: 0.1, // add this
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    displayInput: true,
    fgColor: color,
    readOnly: true,
    draw: function() {
      $(this.i).val(this.cv.toFixed(1) + 'ms').css({
        'font-size': '1em',
        'color': 'black'
      });
    }
  });

  // for testing
  let value = 12.3;
  $('.dial').val(value).trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery-Knob/1.2.13/jquery.knob.min.js" integrity="sha512-NhRZzPdzMOMf005Xmd4JonwPftz4Pe99mRVcFeRDcdCtfjv46zPIi/7ZKScbpHD/V0HB1Eb+ZWigMqw94VUVaw==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<input type="text" class="dial" />
```

Also note that I adjusted the font size of the output so that it fits within the control.